# W3 CSS Modal Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to use a W3 CSS Modal, found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_gallery), to create an image gallery.

Below is the code which displays a number of images which I have stored in a folder.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" CellPadding="5">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a id="imageLink" href='<%# Eval("ImageName","~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' title='<%#Eval("Description") %>' runat="server" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer"
                               onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" cssClass="w3-circle" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' runat="server" Width="50%" Height="84" />
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I replace the above table with this code below, the modal successfully works.:

```
 <img src="SlideImages/one.jpg" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer"
onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity"/>
```

So the problem lies somewhere in the table I think, but I can't figure out where.

Below is the code for the modal:

```
<div id="modal01" class="w3-modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
    <span class="w3-closebtn w3-hover-red w3-text-white w3-xxlarge w3-container w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
        <img id="img01" style="width:100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript

```
<script>
    function onClick(element) {
        document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
        document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

When I click one of the images, the screen begins to get darker, as if the modal is about to appear, but then it just displays like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBvKE.jpg)
I'd really appreciate any advice on what may be the problem

Comment: It sounds a bit like a problem with CSS. Did you try to debug it with the F12 tool?

Comment: @TomasB The <a> tag's are actually appearing for all of the images

Comment: That's a problem with ASP.NET I unfortunatelly can't help you with that. But you should investigate what's wrong after the opening of the image - what the white is and where that style came from so you can fix it.

Comment: @TomasB But the images are displaying on the page when I load it, it is only when I click and I think when I execute the javascript that the problem is occuring. I have attached a screenshot of how the image is appearing above.

Comment: @TomasB Can you look at the modal code above and see the <img /> tag. Before I run my project, there is a green line underneath this adivising me that it is missing the requird 'src' attribute. Could this be causing my issue?

Comment: Okay and how does your code looks like when it's actualy rendered? (So you can spot a difference in what your ASP.NET is rendering and how it should look like compared to the W3Schools example)

Comment: @TomasB I would like it to work like the example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_gallery) I have attached a link at the end of my question which shows a screenshot of how it is actually rendering

Comment: by rendering I meant the code - how it changed the ASP.NET code into actual HTML.

Comment: Please post the applicable CSS definitions to help diagnose your problem. Also, I suggest examining the generated HTML using Chrome "Inspect" or some other view source utility. That may reveal the cause of your problem.